# Using MongoDB Covered Index

Tags: mongodb, database

This is in relation to the MongoDB manual at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-optimization.

I am not understanding the purpose of Covered query. If we have a collection with index on the type and item fields like given below

```
{ type: 1, item: 1 }
```

and if the query is like this

```
db.inventory.find( { type: "food", item:/^c/ },
               { item: 1, _id: 0 } )
```

This will return only item? Why does it only return item? The second part of the MongoDB query
after the find part i.e.

```
    { item: 1, _id: 0 } )
```

what does it signify? What is 0 and 1? 
Why does the query below returns both item and id?

```
 db.inventory.find( { type: "food", item:/^c/ },
               { item: 1 } )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer to the document of [db.collection.find](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/), it says very clear, the 2nd parameter is about which filed to return:

> Optional. Specifies the fields to return using projection operators. To return all fields in the matching document, omit this parameter.

You can use those projection operators of course. But most of the time we just specify which fields to return and which fields are not. So

```
{ item: 1, _id: 0 }
```

means result set should only contain the field item, not _id (because id defaults to be in the result set unless you say no).

Also note in JavaScript world, 1/0 also means true/false. If it helps you to understand. Thus:

```
1 == true  // true
0 == false  // true
```

It's because of the auto conversion in JavaScript. And if you don't want the conversion,

```
1 === true  // false
```